# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function. (consistent-return)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

in my code, I want to iterate over an array of objects, as soon as one of these objects contains the element return true otherwise at the end of loop return false. it seems that my code works but ESLint shows error `[eslint] Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function. (consistent-return)` but I don't want to return for instance `false` if the condition is false.

so my array looks like below. and the function afterward.

```
myArray:[{location:["rowcol","rowcol",...]},{location:[]},{location:[]},...]

  isOccupied(row, col) {
    const { myArray} = state[id];
     myArray.forEach(key => { // here on arrow I see the error
      if(key.location.includes(row+ col)) return true;
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to determine if the statements is true for at least one item.

You should use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function.

This stops looking after it has found the first match.

```
isOccupied(row, col) {
   const { myArray} = state[id];
   return myArray.some(key => key.location.includes(row+col));
}
```